# How to configure multiple isolated networks in VMware that have Internet access?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I know this is a topic that's been discussed at length over the years, but I can't find a sensible answer.

Using VMware Workstation Pro 14 on Windows 10.

I have four guests. I want them to be two pairs.

- The guests in each pair should be able to communicate with each other in the typical TCP/UDP/ICMP sense.
- The guests in each pair should also be able to communicate with the Internet.

However, the guests in one pair should NOT be able to communicate with the guests in the other pair.

It seems the only way to get a VMware guest to communicate with the Internet is via NAT or a bridged connection (according to [here](https://protechgurus.com/connect-vmware-virtual-machine-internet-physical-network/) and [here](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/connect-internet-bridge-nat-vmware-virtualbox/)).

**NAT**

My understanding is that in VMware Workstation Pro you can only have one NAT network (`vmnet8`). So, if my guests are all connected to this NAT network they can see each other. I've tested this - this is true.

**Bridged**

If I bridge the NICs they will be on the same "physical" network and so again, will be able to see each other.

**Two NICs**

I've seen some discussion saying that each guests should have two NICs:

1. For comms with the other guest in the pair.
2. For comms with the Internet.

However, my understanding is that the Internet NIC would still have to be NAT or bridge and so the problem still persists.

**Some Notes**

- According to [the VMware docs](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/14.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D9B0A52D-38A2-45D7-A9EB-987ACE77F93C.html), you can only have one NAT network.
- VirtualBox seems to provide this capability quite simply via the [NAT Network](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes).

Comment: set up a simple router distro VM with 2 NICs, like IPFire as a router.  One NIC is internal to your VMs, the other is NATted or bridged. This allows you to build 2 isolated environments. see 4,5,6 here: https://smudj.wordpress.com/2019/01/23/setting-up-an-all-in-one-windows-ad-test-environment-vmware-workstation-edition/

Comment: Thanks @essjae. Slightly disappointing that I'd have to have a whole other VM, taking up resources, to implement this, but this does seem to be the only way.

Comment: You only need 1 cpu and minimal RAM, so unless you're really resource constrained it's not much for overhead.